# jQuery UI slider - prevent multiple handles from overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, position

I have this fiddle of a slider with four handles. What would be the simplest way to disallow them from crossing each other when you drag them? I tried comparing their position.left values and returning false when they equal an adjacent handle, but that kills the dragging altogether. Ideally, you wouldn't be able to drag it smaller than the width of the select dropdown in between each handle, but I can probably get there if I could just stop them from crossing.

http://jsfiddle.net/0jqs0eeh/7/

```
$(".pct-slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 1440,
    step: 15,
    range: false,
    values: [180, 435, 1080, 1320],
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $.each( initialValues, function(i, v){
            updateValue({
                value: v,
                handle: $('.ui-slider-handle').eq(i) 
            });
        });
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        var handleIndex = $(ui.handle).index();
        updateValue(ui);
        positionSelects();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the handle's `index` using the selector `$('a', event.target).index(ui.handle)`.

From there, you can access the next/previous handle values and compare whether the current handle's value is in between them. If it is, then return false and prevent the handles from overlapping.

In the example below, the value 25 is hardcoded padding that is used to prevent the handles from overlapping.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/g1j2tmhz/)

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
    var handleIndex = $('a', event.target).index(ui.handle),
        curr = ui.values[handleIndex],
        next = ui.values[handleIndex + 1] - 25,
        prev = ui.values[handleIndex - 1] + 25;

    if (curr > next || curr < prev) {
        return false;
    }

    updateValue(ui);
    positionSelects();
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic. For some reason ui.values[handleIndex] is returning undefined on my dev... I'm wondering if it's a jquery version issue. I basically copied the exact code and doing a console.log(curr) or any of the vars returns undefined in the console. 

I'm wondering if there is a syntax issue that works on jsfiddle but may be causing me problems in my environment?

Comment: @KirkRoss I guess the issue would be with `handleIndex` then. What is it returning? Perhaps your markup is different and the wrong `index` is being selected?

Comment: It's getting the handleIndex ok... I think it's when it tries to get the value using ui.values[handleIndex] is the issue. Is there a different / more literal way of writing that line? Like $slider( "values", handleIndex) or something I could try like that?

Comment: @KirkRoss I'm pretty sure that's the only way to retrieve the values. What if you log the array? `console.log(ui.values)`.. compare that with the `handleIndex` to see if the index is within the range of the array. If you can provide an example, I'll take a look.

Comment: It's odd... when I log a hard code of ui.values[0] it returns the value of the first handle, but when I log handleIndex -- as set by $('a', event.target).index(ui.handle); -- then it returns 4 as the index of the first handle, 5 as the second and so forth. Something in my HTML is offsetting the index number. I'll have to dig into this tomorrow... gotta leave work now. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: When I move the 4 select dropdowns from inside the slider it works, so I'm think their presence was somehow disturbing the index count (in my environment). I should note that in my dev I have the slider in a jquery ui tabs() div so that may be playing a role.

Comment: I had a similar issue with other html elements messing up the index. I took them out, then added them back in using append(). The net effect was the same, and the index of the handles was preserved.